# How to send reply message in spring rabbit correctly?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have a spring rabbit listener

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) {
     //do something

      channel.basicPublish("",queue name, null, SerializationUtils.serialize(r));

}
```

How rabbit will understand that this response is for my particular message? In case if I have a thousands of messages. What I need to do to link request and response? And is there a way to pass to the channel POJO without serialization? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take care there about `replyTo` and `correlation`.

But I'd say that there is no reason to do that manually, because `MessageListenerAdapter` takes care about that.

You just need supply a POJO with request-reply capabilities:

```
class Delegate {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public String handleMessage(String input) {
        called.set(true);
        return "processed" + input;
    }
}

adapter.setDelegate(new Delegate());
```

Comment: Thank you ,so in other words, I need to send my object with boolean flag to the consumer, consumer sets this flag to true and pulls back, right? Should be this flag attribute be thread safe? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you talk about. The POJO consumer (`Delegate`) is just responsible to get deal with domain object and knows nothing about AMQP (e.g. `Channel`). No need to send any `boolean` flag. Just send Message as is with desired body (`template.convertSendAndReceive`) and your POJO should accept the domain object as method argument and can return another domain. The `MessageListenerAdapter` will take care about conversions. `SimpleMessageConverter` is used by default.

Comment: Thanks, sorry but I was confused a bit because I did the same from the beginning: return new MessageListenerAdapter(orderSaverListener); So if I understood correctly, I should not care about corellationIDS and so on, and in this question description I should not do anything,right?

Comment: Looks like. At least it works that way in the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#request-reply